# Simple HTML Query about Image and heading

Tags: html, css

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    img.bg {
      /* Set rules to fill background */
      min-height: 100%;
      min-width: 1024px;
        
      /* Set up proportionate scaling */
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
        
      /* Set up positioning */
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;

      z-index: 3;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { /* Specific to this particular image */
      img.bg {
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -512px;   /* 50% */
      }
    }
</style>
    <title>
        Blah blah blah
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <img src="moto_e_card.jpg" class="bg" /> 
    <h1 style="z-index: 10;"> Hello World </h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

I am trying to have a full screen background image inside a div, and top of these div, i need Text. above is my implementation, i know i am missing something really basic, please help.
Why am i not able to see the heading over the image ?
Thanks for all your help in advance.

## Updated

The role of the div is to contain an image which fills up a window, and that div Also holds text on top of the image.

Comment: Why put `style` outside of `head`? In the CSS, I see even more problems. What exactly is your plan here? Could you explain what do you expect from the CSS properties you are using? Just throwing them there randomly? What is the role of that div?

Comment: If you don't mind how the image is cropped, google both "CSS 100% height" and "CSS background cover", remove the `<img>` tag and apply it to your `<div>` via CSS `background-image` or just use http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/ :)

Answer (score 0):

While I am not certain of who you intentd this to be implemented I would suggest setting the img via backround:;

and consider implementing one oth othe methods outlined in the same post you got this code from.

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

also read:
http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/responsive-hero-image-with-text-overlay/

I would suggest doing more research prior to bring it to this forum.

:) - all the best in your learning

Answer (score 0):

I suggest setting the image as a background-image for the div (instead of adding an image tag into the main HTML section), and setting the background size to 100%.  If not that, then setting your img to a z-index of -1, or wrapping your heading in a new div, which would place the heading-containing div in view instead of behind the image.